# How can I get format() to return a 1-character result?

Tags: r

`format(Sys.Date(),"%m")` returns `"07"`, but I'd like it to return `"7"` while still returning two characters when needed.  adding `width=8` to the argument list doesn't help, nor does anything else I've tried.

My end goal is to make the stock quote reading function on p. 182 of R in a Nutshell work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Many ways to do it, but substr() might work best. Combine with ifelse() for two digits.

```
as.character(as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),"%m")))

as.character(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$mon + 1)

substr(format(Sys.Date(),"%m"), 2, 2)
```

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks.  I've been playing around manually with the command to Nutshell's get.quotes and then doing a manual read.csv, and I think that was a false alarm.  I'm not sure that's the problem, but I'll check it out.

Perhaps my real question should have been how to get that function to work.

Comment: What are your errors? looks like the book is Google Preview-able: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596801717/preview

Comment: The substr() example will only return the last digit of the the numeric month, which is not the desired result for October to December.

Comment: m <- format(Sys.Date(), "%m");
substr(m, ifelse(as.numeric(m) < 10, 2, 1), 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` to remove the leading zeros:

```
> gsub('^0','',format(Sys.Date(),"%m"),perl=TRUE)
[1] "7"
> gsub('^0','',format(as.Date('2010-10-10'),"%m"),perl=TRUE)
[1] "10"
```